# whose view is not in the windows heirarchy

Tags: mvvm, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers in the other questions worked for me. Here is my code:

```

```
var values = [String: AnyObject]()

func loginUserToFirebase(_ completion: () -> Void) {
    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
    guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else {fatalError()}
    let credentials = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "Something went wrong")
            return
        }
        self.fbGraphRequest()
    })
}

internal func fbGraphRequest(){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "error unknown")
            return
        } else {
            print(result ?? "no result")
            self.values = result as! [String: AnyObject]
            print(self.values)
            weak var rootViewModel = RootViewModel()
            rootViewModel?.values = self.values
            self.presentRootViewController()
        }
    }
}

internal func presentRootViewController() {
    let loginController = LoginController()
    let rootViewController = RootViewController()
        loginController.present(rootViewController, animated: true, 
completion: nil)

}
```

```

and here is my error: 

`Attempt to present <Art_Cache.RootViewController: 0x7fa6a1c2aab0> on <Art_Cache.LoginController: 0x7fa6a1c840b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

This snippet worked when I had this in my LoginViewController and I used `self.present(rootViewController, animation: true, completion: nil)`. Im trying to convert my project to MVVM and this is what's happening. The problem seems to be around the `self.presentRootViewController()`. These functions are fired upon pressing the facebook login button. Please help and cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you current view controller's is not the part of window, could you change

```
func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
        }

        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController

            if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController, top.view.window != nil {
                return topViewController(top)
            } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(selected)
            }
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(presented)
        }

        return base
    }


    topViewController()?.present(rootViewController, animated: true, 
    completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You are a rockstar! I have tried a variation of this code but it didnt work so I didnt think it was the `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.rootViewcontroller` was the problem. Again thank you!

Comment: You even included a nav and tab selection. You truly are a rockstar!